# Google App Engine to Calendar Authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am new to App Engine and am trying to write an application which will access Google Calendar to get details of any events for the current time. I am struggling to see how the authentication should work to permit access to Calendar. I believe OAuth2 is the preferred authentication option so I have a client_secrets.json file with the ClientID and Client Secret from an API Access project I have separately created:

```
{
"web":{
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"client_secret":"xxxxxxx",
"token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"client_email":"xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"redirect_uris":["https://myapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback"],
"client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"client_id":"123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"javascript_origins":["https://myapp.appspot.com"]
}
}
```

This was a direct export from the API Access project using the 'Download JSON' option. When I deploy my app engine application I get an error:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://myapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback did not match a registered redirect URI
Learn more
Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=https://myapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback
display=page
client_id=123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

It all looks fine to me so I am not sure what the error is telling me. Do I need link the App Engine application to the API Access project in some way. Am I missing something else fundamental.

If there is any additional information which will help you understand the set up please let me know. I wanted to keep the post small.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comment [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) that says:

> When you created your credentials, you probably indicated that the
>   client credentials you were creating were for a web application
>   instead of an installed application. When you do that, you enter a
>   Redirect URI for that set of credentials. The sample you are using is
>   using the out of band Redirect URI for installed applications which
>   does not match the one you specified, so it will not allow you to
>   compete the authentication flow. This is to protect you from malicious
>   use of your client credentials. Open the APIs console and create a new
>   client ID for "installed applications" instead of "web applications"
>   and this should work.

Did you set up a web application or an installed application?

Comment: I am trying to set up for a web application running on Google App Engine. Is something still wrong for a web application? Thanks James